# $.post not working in subdirectory folder created in IIS

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, spring-mvc, jquery-mobile

We developing Web application using MVC4. In button click i used $.post in jquery to call my action method everything works fine until we moved all our code to newly created subdirectory in IIS.

befor the path is

http://10.111.151.99.9999/

Every thing works fine in above url but when we moved all our code to newly created sub folder like

http://10.111.151.99.9999/MobAPP

all my jquery call gets failed. below is my code.

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnDpadjQty', function (e) {
       var url = "/Home/Index";
       var qty = $("#txtDPPkd").val();
       var pwd = $("#Password").val()
       $.post(url, { QTY: qty, PWD: pwd }, function (data) {
           if (data.toUpperCase() == "ADJUST SUCCESS") {
               $().toastmessage('showSuccessToast', "Quantity Adjusted Successfully");
               $("#txtPickedQuantity").val(qty);
               $('#dvDPPopup').popup("close");
           }
           else {
               $().toastmessage('showErrorToast', "Password Incorrect");
           }
       });
   });
```

Below is my action method

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index(int QTY, string PWD)
        {
            return Json(sucess);

}
```

Its work perfectly before creating subfolder in iis. Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

Your url is not right because your project is in subdirectory and your url is hardcoded which is wrong and should not be done this way, you should use **Url.Action() helper for generating urls**:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
```

Comment: great i will try. one doubt. In future if i deployed  my code without subdirectory will it work?

Comment: ``Url.Action()`` alwasys generates correct url, regardless in which direcotry you place it in IIS

Comment: Sajid: sorry i tried below code 

var url = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';


But it not hitting my controller itself.